# Cannot Install SRC - Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am failing to install SRC in Linux Mint 19 via PIP. I have attempted to paste the output and failed horribly, I have had to double space everything, otherwise, it comes out as one long run-on sentence. Not sure how to paste a readable output of my Linux terminal here. Sorry.....

```
Failed building wheel for src
Running setup.py clean for src
Failed to build src
Installing collected packages: src
Running setup.py install for src ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l2mswq/src/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-AeHl8U-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    error: error in command line: command 'InstallCommand' has no such option 
'compile'

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-
build-l2mswq/src/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AeHl8U-record/install-record.txt -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error 
code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l2mswq/src/
```

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install src
```

tries to install [src from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/src/) — a package specifically created to not to be installed.

What are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm attempting to run a small Python script that seems to need this SRC package/function/whatever.

Comment: If I try running my script in the terminal I get:

ValueError: 'src' is not in the list

Comment: Turns out I'm completely off base. SRC is just a line in a file im searching for. And .index is not seeing it for whatever reason. I'm dumb.